# Does being a dark elf fully negate sun damage as a vampire lord

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

If I am a dark elf will I get no penalties from being in the sun, like, will my health stamina and magicka still regenerate?

Comment: I removed the second question about if you should go with vampire or dawnguard as that is a subjective question which don't work well on this site. They're both equally viable and give different stories, do what you want :)

Answer (score 7):

No, every race will get the same downsides from vampirism, namely reduction of attributes (health/magicka/stamina, -15 in stage 1, then -30, -45 and -60 for the latter stages) and 100% reduction of regeneration for them in the sun.

Comment: Dark elf has 50% resistance to fire so ...

Comment: Yes, which isn't sun, they just have resistance to fire spells.

Comment: Proof of this: Dawnguard added a Restoration spell that does Sun damage against vampires and undead. This spell won't harm other races at all, including non-vampire dark elves. Even if sun damage were the same as fire damage, the vampiric penalties aren't exressed as damage, but as reductions. Damage reduction woudln't affect this.

Comment: @TheElectricMoose Sun != Fire. These are different elements. Even though every vampire has a weakness against fire, which will be affected by the dark elf race.

Answer (score 0):

Being a dark elf merely negates the weakness to fire(50% at level 4), not temporary stat reductions from being in the sun. On the flip side, as a level 4 vampire you would be 50% resistant to frost, making you extremely similar to a baseline nord.